# Detect only letters from input text (error using javascript)

Tags: javascript, jsp

The function I wrote check if the input is a letter or not. If not it shows an alert  message then erases the content. It works fine when I just enter a letter, but if I enter numbers, it shows the message to enter letters which is ok, but when I enter letters in the box, it still pops up the message and ask me to enter a letter. Why? How can I fix it?

```
<%//javascript file %>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function allLetter(value)  
{  
 var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
 if(value.match(letters))  
   {
    return true;  
   }  
 else  
   {  
   alert("first, last and middle name contain only letters");  
   return false;  
   }  
} 

function checkform ( form )
{
  // see http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/validation.shtml
  // for an explanation of this script and how to use it on your
  // own website

  // ** START **
  if ((form.firstName.value == "") || (form.lastName.value == "") ) {
    alert("Please enter both your first and last name.");
    form.firstName.focus();
    form.lastName.focus();
    return false ;
  }
  // ** END **
  return true ;
}
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Names and country of residence page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

    // Registering Postgresql JDBC driver with the DriverManager
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    // Open a connection to the database using DriverManager
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/assignment1",
        "postgres","Km81920265");


        // Create the statement
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        // Use the created statement to SELECT
        // the student attributes FROM the Student table.
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM countries_and_states WHERE is_country='t'");


%>

<%//first delcare input %>
Please enter your first name, last name and middle initial:<p>
<form method="get" action="address.jsp" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<%//store input into session %>
Your first name :<input type="text" size="15" name="firstName" onchange="if(!allLetter(this.value)){this.value= ' ';} "/><p/>
Your last name  :<input type="text" size="15" name="lastName" onchange="if(!allLetter(this.value)){this.value= ' ';} "/><p/>
Your middle name:<input type="text" size="15" name="middleName" onchange="if(!allLetter(this.value)){this.value= ' ';} "/><p/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change letters to match `/^\s*[A-Za-z]+\s*$/` or trim the whitespace around the value.

Comment: It ignores spaces on the beginning and end of the value.

Comment: `^` matches beginning of string, `\s` means a white space character, `*` means zero or more, so `\s*` is zero or more white space characters.  `[A-Za-z]` is of course letters in the range A-Z or a-z, `+` is one or  more, and `$` is end of string.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 2):

You set the value to a space, which is not a letter.

It is also worth noting that some people have spaces in their names.  The same is true for numbers.

Comment: but i need to set the value to space after this.value is not letters

Comment: @keivn, I see no reason for you to need to do that.

Comment: because i need to prevent user to type number before they submit

Comment: When you have `this.value= ' ';` why not use `this.value= '';` instead?